# Calling jQuery from a textbox event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to use an [input mask](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/tree/1.3.1) in a `smarty` template.

This is the text box with an inline `event` handler:

```
<input type="text" name="{$fldname"} id ="{$fldname}" value="{$fldvalue}" onKeyUp="jQuery(function($){$("#phone").mask("999-999-9999",{placeholder:"_");});">
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: How do you make what work ?

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9QeQA/))

**HTML:** (Assumed `$fldname` contains `phone`)

```
<input type="text" name="{$fldname}" id ="{$fldname}" value="{$fldvalue}" />
```

**JS:** (Put this between `<head></head>` tags)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#phone").mask( "999-999-9999", { placeholder : "_" } );
    });
</script>
```